# In cycles, how do I make this kind of fur?

Tags: texturing

I wish to be able to design the fur seen on the head, minus the fabric rip. Where some parts are elevated more than others and how the thickness and depth varies is desirable. A must is to avoid using a particle system to reduce render times.

I would want to do this to a character from head to toe.
What would be a practical way to recreate this?

[image]

Comment: It is just texture with normal map and some of the bigger chunks and details are also supported with geometry. You get the normal map by baking from sculpted highpoly. Try it and post results, we can go further from there.

Comment: @Jaroslav Jerryno Novotny Please show me how to do this, then we can go further from here. When I try to do anything like this is never looks like I want it to look. I am sure I am doing it incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a classic combination of normal mapping and a few volumes detailing in the mesh.

They probably sculpted a high-resolution mesh with all the "spikes", then created a low poly version where they basically kept only the important and silhouette defining geometry, then baked the high resolution's details into a normal map applied to the low poly to fake the details. Add to this a good touch of color painting, and here you go.

Comment: I'm not asking how they did it, I'm asking what are the step needed to make this.

Comment: Come on!  
There are plenty tutorials and How-tos on the Internet to learn how to do these things. We will not make a custom tutorial for you... We are not supposed to hold your hand from the beginning and lead you where you want. We can help you when you're stuck, but you have to try and show what you did first.